# Which Excel's formula can do this without VBA UDF?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm bad in describe idea in English sothat I can't find the solution for this task, then I write a custom UDF for excel

```
Public Function ArrCompare(Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range) As Variant
Dim vR1, strC As String
Dim i As Long, Ui As Long
vR1 = Rng1.Value2
strC = Rng2.Cells(1, 1).Value2
Ui = UBound(vR1)
For i = 1 To Ui
    If InStr(1, strC, vR1(i, 1), vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then vR1(i, 1) = True Else vR1(i, 1) = False
Next
ArrCompare = vR1
End Function
```

But I'm really want to know what native combine function can do this or which formula can do it ?

Example:
I have 5 cells (A1:A5) with value like this:

```
111
112
113
114
115
```

and I have a string content "`111,113,117,110`" in B1.
I write that UDF to use in Sumproduct like this

```
=Sumproduct(--Arrcompare(A1:A5, B1)) in cell C1.
```

it will return total cells that match my condition.

Does anyone know what formula can do this without vba ?

Answer (score 2):

The formula which will do the same as your UDF would be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1:A5,B1)))
```

But I would exclude empty cells in the range, so that the range can be bigger to be prepared for additional values:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$1:$A$100,B1))*($A$1:$A$100<>""))
```

Comment: Thank you, I did think about that formula too, and then I false to write it in complex function, I tho It can't be use haha. can't believe it work... oh my head... (I findout that UDF alittle faster than native combine Isnumber(search())... don't know why yet)

Comment: ++ Nicely Done :)

Answer (score 2):

You could actually use COUNTIF for that:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(B1,"*"&A1:A5&"*"))
```

Comment: well, I capture the screen shoot for you, may be something wrong happen between us lol...
[Image link](https://postimg.org/image/f4sfaqizp/)

Comment: @Sum I'm afraid that site is blocked by work policies. Here's a link to a working workbook: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsDYl-5bgVQWgP8uG90__atmY0IfIA

Comment: @Rory OMG, lol, downloaded workbook work, but the same data in my PC not work... and I findout "number,number,number" will confuse excel as number with coma as number format... Great job, Rory

Comment: I think this method having best performance among all formula solution. it still take 120% calculate time compared to UDF, but i'll take it with appreciated. 1 up for you.

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers are not always 3 digits, this array formula should be a tiny bit more reliable as it will search for `,111,` in `,111,113,117,110,`:

```
{=SUM(1-ISERR(FIND(","&A1:A5&",",","&B1&",")))}
```

or just

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1-ISERR(FIND(","&A1:A5&",",","&B1&",")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar with `@Rory` variant, but little bit different:

```
{=SUM(COUNTIF(B1,"*"&A1:A5&"*"))}
```

[image]

---

Similar with `@Axel Richter`, but also has some difference:

```
{=COUNT(SEARCH(A1:A5,B1,1))}
```

[image]

insert the formula onto and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to get formula array `{}`

Comment: formula array will decrease performance unless it's MultiRange formula. I'll test with sumproduct + countif, search/Find method slower than vba. thank

Comment: @Sum you've asked the formula, no matter does it has better performance than already provided variants or not, I've posted additional variants only because such variants should be here also, and that's why I've specified that these variants similar with already provided.